# "Outlook is closing" in Notification Tray - Do I need to kill the process everytime I want to use it?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I try to open the program - nothing happens - and I notice it's greyed out icon is in the notification tray - mouse over reveals "Outlook is closing". So my routine now is to kill the process but it is getting a little tiresome. What would be causing this?

I have no addons running.
It is not set to empty deleted folder on exit.
The is no indication in event viewer of any issues.
When "Outlook is closing", Task Manager > Processes reveals it is using 65MB of memory but nothing else. No CPU usage, Disk or Network!

OS: Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit
Office: Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2021
Add-Ins: NONE
Processor: AMD Ryzen 9 3900X 12-Core
Ram: 64GB

I have tried everything suggested on Google.
Killing the process is not a solution!

This issue is driving me nuts - so much that I'm tempted to ditch MS Office and use Windows Mail instead - which I would keep using if it didn't have it's own issues (attached pdfs not visible).
Like another user - I can't believe I actually paid for this software

Comment: "Outlook is closing" in Notification Tray - Do I need to kill the process every time I want to use it?  .....   Does not and has not happened to me here (except in the odd instance of a problem).  Try:   Uninstall Office, restart and install / patch Office. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to my search, there are several factors for Outlook shutdown issues, it is recommended you try the following troubleshooting:

- Make sure that you have upgraded it to the latest version via File > Office Account > Upate Options > Update Now.
- Check whether antivirus software is up-to-date or conflicts with Outlook
  If your antivirus software is not up-to-date, Outlook may not function correctly.
- A corrupted profile may cause this problem, so you can delete the old profile and create a new profile from control panel > Mail > Show profiles > re-add your account to test.
- If the issue continues, it is suggested [repair office from control panel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)
- Perform a clean boot,for more information about performing a clean boot, see [How to perform a clean boot in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows-da2f9573-6eec-00ad-2f8a-a97a1807f3dd)

Hope this can help you!
If you think my answer is helpful to you, please kindly accept this answer.